# Python Pandas_How to select data after using drop_duplicates()?

Tags: python, pandas

I am learning python pandas to processing data.

1. I firstly using `drop_duplicates()` method to treat `db_new` and get `a`;
2. Then I'd like to find what kind of data in a using `print`;
3. I try to find if a data is in a using `for...in`, but I found that even the data in a can not be find in it, why?

[image: I found 9 is not in a]

```
a = db_new.iloc[:i,4:5].drop_duplicates()
print a
for x in a:
    print x**
```

4. I try to use `for in` to find what can get in a. I only get `E`, which is the column index. Do you know why this happen?

Comment: I don't get it : "I found that even the data in 'a' can not be found in it".

Comment: What do you mean by the "kind of data"? Are you asking for the *type*? If so, `.dtypes` on any DataFrame will tell you what each column represents.

Answer (score 1):

Here `a` is a dataframe, so when you iterate over `a` you iterate over column names, hence the result, `E`.

If you want to iterate over values, you need to make `a` a series, which you can do using `squeeze`:

```
for x in a.squeeze():
    print x
```